# UPS for tiny load

Tags: ups

I am looking for UPS to backup 1 cable modem, and 1 mikrotik router. 
I have been trying a brand, but but it was shutdown after a few minutes because its load was under 1%. Both devices measured at around 3 - 4 Watts

Any advice which UPS should I buy?

Thank you

Comment: I doubt you can find ANY UPS being able to deliver less then 10 W. I'm not aware of their existence. The circuitry in a UPS requires a minimal load (typically >25W) to operate properly. Your best bet is a very small UPS (150-200VA) and add a little extra load to it. A hub or small switch is probably enough. A small light-bulb can also work, if you are not bothered by the light being always on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[APC BackUPS](http://www.apc.com/products/family/index.cfm?id=29) is probably the best fit, designed for home computer applications.

You should be able to find one with your [local power socket format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets).

I can't find any evidence on the APC website about the UPS having a minimum power draw...

Comment: Yes, but I have contacted APC's representatives here, and they said that their UPS won't function properly with such a low load. I am asking APC directly via their website to confirm. Is there any other suggestion? Brand, or based on your experience, which one can perform correctly?

Comment: Tom is right. APC is the best bet. I have a APC BackupUPS 650 with a single switch on it drawing 2 watts, never had any issues *touches wood*

Comment: I have the BackUPS 650 as well, and I won't shutdown with no load. However, there are serious drawbacks to that thing. Look at [my review](http://www.halfgaar.net/apc-ups-cs-650-review).

Comment: I've never seen a UPS shutdown because it wasn't loaded (enough.)  I guess it's a big fat case of YMMV.

Comment: Mine has :D. Anyway I have received an answer from APC, they suggest BE350G